# How do I get the second row of strings in a text file in PHP

Tags: php

I am tasked to get the surname of the person and put it on a table as all capital letters. How do I do it with a loop?

I've already gotten the full name for the first row. I don't know how to get the last name for the 2nd row though.

```
<html>
<title> Task 4 </title>
<style>
  table, td, th { border: 1px black solid; border-collapse: collapse; }
  p { padding: 0px; margin:0px; font-family: monospace;}
</style>
<body>
<h1> Task 4: PHP Program #2 </h1>
<?php  /* Write your code here */

print "<table> \n";
print "<th> Full Name </th> <th> Surname only </th> \n";

$names = file("names.txt");
for ($i = 0;$i<sizeof($names);$i++){
    print "<tr><td>$names[$i]</td><td></td></tr>\n";
  }

print "</table> \n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The list of names in the text file is this

```
Abdel Zhang
Terry Deaner
Didi Xiong
Kate Sanko
Seonjoo Kim
Rang Nyguen
Zheng Lu
Robert Smith
Donald Trump
Crack Stuntman
Meredith Jones
Abdullah Afifi
Hakki Kamier
```

Comment: You are trying to get the second row or last name? You could explode on the space then use the last index.

Comment: trying to put the last names 2nd column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, the name is always divided by an simple space, you could just use `explode`.

```
$parts = explode(' ', $line[$i]);
$firstname = $parts[0];
$lastname = $parts[1];
```